# RSpec - Get Described Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How can I get the main class that is being described in RSpec 3? For example, I have the following spec:

```
describe User do
  describe "fetching" do
    describe "all" do
      subject { described_class.new }
    end
  end
end
```

`subject` currently returns something similar to `User::fetching::all` but I want it to return `User` only.

Comment: Did you find a solution that you wanted?

Comment: @PaulFioravanti I don't remember what I did but I think the reason why it wasn't working for me was because I had to add `type: :model` to the describe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure I'm understanding your question correctly, but as far as I can see, if you just want to get the class name constant within your test, just using `described_class` (without `.new`) should get you what you want:

```
class User; end

describe User do
  subject { described_class }
  it { is_expected.to eq(User) }
end
```